# Is a way to improve quality of this 3D map chart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using a JFreeChart library in my Java project. I'm wondering if is a way to draw this chart more smoothly? With no such big pixels.

[image: XYBlockChart]

To generate this chart I'm using XYBlockRenderer.

Comment: Without more data, you'll have to [upsample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsampling) using some [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) method.